# Methods in Collections class not having null check for input collection

Tags: java, collections

While working on my code, I used the `Collections` and came across something which seems very wierd to me. I wonder why this questions was never asked earlier although this class and the method I am referring to have **been there from Java 1.4**

```
/**
 * Returns an array list containing the elements returned by the
 * specified enumeration in the order they are returned by the
 * enumeration.  This method provides interoperability between
 * legacy APIs that return enumerations and new APIs that require
 * collections.
 *
 * @param e enumeration providing elements for the returned
 *          array list
 * @return an array list containing the elements returned
 *         by the specified enumeration.
 * @since 1.4
 * @see Enumeration
 * @see ArrayList
 */
public static <T> ArrayList<T> list(Enumeration<T> e) {
    ArrayList<T> l = new ArrayList<>();
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
        l.add(e.nextElement());
    return l;
}
```

This is the method that I was going through. I am really curious to know why the API is not written cleanly (I think).

1. There is no `null` check for the input collection, which is something which a standard API should always consider.
2. The created `ArrayList` is stored in a reference of `ArrayList`, which one would have normally stored in a `List` reference. Same is the case with the return type as well.

I din't raise bugs for this in the Java bug repo, as the Javadoc already indicates, that these cases are known.

Any pointers?

Comment: Err, because it isn't specified to do so? Or because they forgot? What does it matter why? You still do get a `NullPointerException` pretty damn quick.

Comment: It isn't intrinsically wrong to specify a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The null check would check for null, and throw a NullPointerException if null. But that's redundant with the call to `e.hasMoreElements()` which has the same effect if `e` is null.

The designer chose to be specific about the type of List that the method returns. He wants to be explicit that a copy of the enumeration is made into a new ArrayList and that an ArrayList is returned. That prevents future versions of Java to return another List implementation, but that's very unlikely to happen, and it gives more information to the caller, which can rely on this list to be an ArrayList. Nothing fundamentally wrong with that.

Comment: Although I agree with your second explanation, I have a new query for the first. Below is the link to an article on best practices to avoid NPEs.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/05/ava-tips-and-best-practices-to-avoid-nullpointerexception-program-application.html

Here point 4 indicates that, when there is chance of a null list, one should return an empty list. Couldn't this be opted for in the above example?

Comment: @TechSpellBound Of course it *could*, although this method doesn't return null, it throws an NPE. It would, however, be a backwards-incompatible change. It isn't difficult to find stuff that could have been improved in the Java libraries; this seems pretty minor compared to real design issues.